# Questions on covering space

Tags: general-topology

Following is a paragraph of a paper I am reading:
[image: covering space]

But I cannot understand this image, maybe it is because I have no idea about coverings. Could anyone explain it to me?

Particularly, you could just explain to me: what does $X_{|U_\alpha}$ mean?

Comment: $X|_{U_\alpha}$ is $p^{-1}(U_\alpha)$. For the rest, just (re)read the definition of covering spaces (say on wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X|_{U_\alpha}$ should mean "the preimage of $U_\alpha$ in $X$". The rest is just a reinterpretation of the definition of covering map/covering space with a nice little diagram.